# Pygame sprite won't show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I started creating a new game in pygame. first I made the game window and background. I made to backgrounds(bg and fg). I was going to leave fg as it was and make the second backgound, bg, as a scrolling background when my character sprite moves. After that, I pasted in code from a previous pygame project that was just a simple sprite character that could walk and jump in front of a background. When I pasted it in, the window came up and only displayed my backgrounds and did not show my sprite character at all. It also did not throw any errors. what's happening? Is my sprite just hidden?

```
import pygame
from random import randint, choice
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#(pasted code start)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Examples/Ben-Game/ben characters main/R %s.png' % frame) for frame in range(1, 9)]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Examples/Ben-Game/ben characters main/L %s.png' % frame) for frame in range(14, 21)]
#(pasted code end)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


bg = pygame.image.load('/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Llama game/Llama imaging/backgrounds concepts/Mountains/PPP_BG1.png')
fg = pygame.image.load('/Users/luke.redwine/Documents/Python/PyGame/Llama game/Llama imaging/backgrounds concepts/Mountains/PPP_fg1.png')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((276, 216), HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE) 

#(pasted code start)---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x, y, width, height):          
        self.x = x                                   
        self.y = y                          
        self.width = width                            
        self.height = height                          
        self.velocity = 15
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 7
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.screen = screen

  def draw(self, screen):                         

        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 8:  
            self.walkCount = 0      

        if self.left:
            self.screen.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount//1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            self.screen.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount//1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

        else:
            self.screen.blit(char, (self.x, self.y))

#(pasted code end)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(bg,(276, 216)),(0,0))
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fg,(276, 216)),(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()


#while loop for screen resize, fulscreen:
while True:
    pygame.event.pump() 
    event=pygame.event.wait()                                                                                     

if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()                                              

elif event.type==VIDEORESIZE:                                                           
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode(event.dict['size'],HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE)
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(bg,event.dict['size']),(0,0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(fg,event.dict['size']),(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()




#(pasted code start)---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#drawing in sprite character
def redrawGamescreen():                      
    ben.screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    ben.screen.blit(fg,(0,0))
    ben.draw(ben.screen)
    pygame.display.update()

ben = player(50, 279, 64, 64)
run = True                                           

#main loop and character control                                                     

while run:
    clock.tick(8)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and ben.x > ben.velocity:
        ben.x -= ben.velocity
        ben.left = True
        ben.right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and ben.x < 735 - ben.width - ben.velocity:
        ben.x += ben.velocity
        ben.right = True
        ben.left = False
    else:
        ben.right = False
        ben.left = False
        ben.walkCount = 0

    if not(ben.isJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            ben.isJump = True
            ben.right = False
            ben.left = False

    else:
        if ben.jumpCount >= -7:
            neg = 1        


            if ben.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1

            ben.y -= (ben.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg 
            ben.jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            ben.isJump = False
            ben.jumpCount = 7 
            ben.velocity = 15

    redrawGamescreen()      
#(pasted code end)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: if you have problem then use `print()` to see which part of code is execute and what values you have in variables. It is called "print debugging". OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: you have two `while True` loop - which one is executed when you run script ?

Comment: to better organize code you should put all classes and functions before `pygame.init()`. Maybe then you will see that you run two `while True` loops and it can make your problem.

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class Player` - and `lower_case_names` for functions - ie. `redraw_game_screen`. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but if you better organize code then you should see that you run two `while` loop. In first loop you display only background. And you never ends first loop so it never run second loop which draws sprite on background. You should remove first loop.